# how to listen docker events and run command when new event emit?

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line, docker

I know `docker events` command can listen docker events, but how to watch `docker events` 's output and run command when have new output?

Comment: You could pipe the standard output of the docker events command into standard input stream, then parse whatever you want and respond to it

Comment: This is a rather open ended "how do I program" question.

Comment: [`docker-events`](https://github.com/diefans/docker-events)